# Map Filtered JSON Links to Filter JSON Nodes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I have node and link data for a force directed graph. Links may have `num` of one, two, or three links between them:

```
{"nodes": [{"id": "Michael Scott", "type": "boss"}
          ,{"id": "Jim Halpert", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Pam Beasley", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Kevin Malone", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Angela", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Dwight Schrute", "type": "employee"}]
,"links": [{"source": "Michael Scott", "target": "Jim Halpert", "num": 1}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "num": 2}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "num": 2}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "num": 3}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "num": 3}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "num": 3}]
}
```

I have a dropdown which should drive filtering of nodes and links for a d3 force-directed graph, based on `num`. I have this code so far to filter the JSON node and link data

```
var dropdown = d3.select("#selectLinkNumber")
var change = function() {
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()
var val = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
    var filteredLinks = graph.links.filter(d => d.num >= val);
    //Needs some way to map unique source and targets to id in nodes
    var filteredNodes = graph.nodes.filter()//Needs some way to fill node filtering with mapping from filteredLinks
      });

    var filteredGraph = {
          nodes: filteredNodes,
          links: filteredLinks
      };
    //do stuff
    })
}
dropdown.on("change", change)
change();
```

How would I finish the JavaScript array manipulation code to filter out links based on `num`, and also filter out the corresponding nodes?

Comment: Don't think of it as filtering the nodes -- think of it as rebuilding the node list after you have filtered the links. After filtering the links, iterate through them and add any `source` or `target` you have not yet encountered back into the `nodes` array.

Comment: Thank you for that insight - definitely helps to think about it in that way. So I believe I need to use the JS array method `map` to iterate through. How would I make sure only unique sources and targets are found and unioned together (to use SQL terminology)? And how would I then match the original nodes array to this new, one element array?

Comment: I updated my question with extra info in the nodes. In other words, I need to retain info from the original nodes array, not just pull unique `source` and unique `target` from the filtered links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the node `id`s as keys to an object to ensure they're only added once, and the nodes array is only filtered once per `id`. This assumes no node is linked to itself, but that would be an unusual edge case.

```
var filteredNodes = Object.values(filteredLinks.reduce(function(t,v){
  if(!t[v.source]){
    t[v.source] = graph.nodes.filter(o => o.id === v.source)[0]
  }
  if(!t[v.target]){
    t[v.target] = graph.nodes.filter(o => o.id === v.target)[0]
  }
  return t;
},{}))
```

Comment: Thank you - that makes logical sense. I plugged that in to my existing code and replaced all instances of `graph` with `filteredGraph`, and now the network doesn't appear (although the SVG legends do). No error shows on the console.

Comment: As a side question - how would one include multiple filters like this on multiple JSON attributes? Seems like it would require nesting of the functions at the top of the code - but that could get messy really quickly.

Comment: Filtering the links just requires a simple 'or': `d.num >= val || d.size >= someOtherVal`. The nodes filter wouldn't need to change.